# Create a nested array of object from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects that I need to turn into nested array based on the time

```
let item = [
  {
    id: 1,
    time: '2018-03-04T07:14:20.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    time: '2018-03-04T07:18:30.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    time: '2018-03-04T07:14:30.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    time: '2018-03-04T07:18:20.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    time: '2018-03-04T07:18:40.000Z'
  }
]
```

What I wanted was to create a nested array of objects based on the time difference of 1 minute. The end result should look something like this

```
item = [
 [
  {
    id: 1,
    time: '2018-03-04T07:14:20.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    time: '2018-03-04T07:14:30.000Z'
  },
 ],
 [
  {
    id: 3,
    time: '2018-03-04T07:18:20.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    time: '2018-03-04T07:18:30.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    time: '2018-03-04T07:18:40.000Z'
  }
 ]
]
```

I tried using arr.reduce() but I'm kinda stuck on how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to summarise the array into an object using the year, month, day, hour and minute as key (The first 16 characters).

Use `Object.values` to convert the object into an array.

```js
let item = [{"id":1,"time":"2018-03-04T07:14:20.000Z"},{"id":2,"time":"2018-03-04T07:18:30.000Z"},{"id":3,"time":"2018-03-04T07:14:30.000Z"},{"id":4,"time":"2018-03-04T07:18:20.000Z"},{"id":5,"time":"2018-03-04T07:18:40.000Z"}]

let result = Object.values(item.reduce((c, v) => {
  let k = v.time.substr(0, 16);
  c[k] = c[k] || [];
  c[k].push(v);
  return c;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

---

You can use `sort` to arrange the array from earliest to latest. Use `reduce` to group the array.

```js
let item = [{"id":1,"time":"2018-03-04T07:14:20.000Z"},{"id":2,"time":"2018-03-04T07:18:30.000Z"},{"id":3,"time":"2018-03-04T07:14:30.000Z"},{"id":4,"time":"2018-03-04T07:18:20.000Z"},{"id":5,"time":"2018-03-04T07:18:40.000Z"},{"id":6,"time":"2018-03-04T07:15:00.000Z"}]

let temp = null;
let result = [...item].sort((a, b) => new Date(a.time).getTime() - new Date(b.time).getTime())
  .reduce((c, v) => {
    let diff = new Date(v.time).getTime() - new Date(temp).getTime();
    if (temp === null || diff > 60000) c.push([v])
    else c[c.length - 1].push(v);
    temp = v.time;
    return c;
  }, []);


console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. One more question. What if I have a another object which has a time of  `"time": "2018-03-04T07:15:00.000Z"` . It should belong to the first nested array because they have a difference of less than a minute. How should I go about that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That will be very broad logic because time will be like `2018-03-04T07:14:00.000Z, 2018-03-04T07:14:15.000Z, 2018-03-04T07:14:30.000Z, 2018-03-04T07:15:00.000Z, 2018-03-04T07:15:40.000Z, 2018-03-04T07:16:10.000Z`.

Comment: On the example the first and last time are more than 1 min apart. Can you explain the logic further?

Comment: Yes something like that. To be on the same array, the time must not go beyond 1 min difference. The example you gave above is should be in one array. Once the time go beyond 1 min, it will be push to a new array. Expanding on your example above, let's say I have another time `2018-03-04T07:18:10.000Z`, this time should be put in a new array because it has a more than one minute difference than `2018-03-04T07:16:10.000Z`

Comment: So for the reply example you gave, everything should be in one array because the subsequent time doesnt have a 1 minute difference between them. The logic is I must compare the current time with the next time

Comment: I added a new block of code. Please check. @Irsyad14